# Postgres query combination of 2 specific string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table movies and nationality field, but it written diferently even if is the same information

```
example:
Británica Estadounidense
estadounidense Británica 
Británica y estadounidense
```

My query is that I have to get all the movies that are británica and estadounidense

My code:

```
SELECT query_name, nationality 
FROM directors 
WHERE nationality LIKE  '%ritánica%' || '%' || '%st%'
```

I don't know how to get when the 2 words are switched `estadounidense Británica`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use regex here to match entire words, regardless of case:

```sql
SELECT query_name, nationality
FROM directors 
WHERE nationality ~* '\yBritánica\y' AND nationality ~* '\yEstadounidense\y';
```

Comment: is not matching the `estadounidense británica`

Comment: @foxDev Your data is the problem and both Gordon's and my answer should be working for you.

Answer (score 1):

One method is two `like`s:

```
SELECT query_name, nationality 
FROM directors 
WHERE nationality LIKE '%ritánica%' AND
      nationality LIKE '%st%'
```

This would, of course, also work for the full names as well.

Comment: is not matching the `estadounidense británica` @GordonLinoff

Comment: @foxDev . . . It certainly should be.  I see both subqueries in that string.